# How to create CIDR IP address/Range in IPv4 in python?

Tags: python, cidr

How do I convert a IPv4 subnet mask to CIDR range? I have subnet and gateway information available.

Data available:

- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.0.2.250
- Expected CIDR notation: 192.0.2.0/24

I know using `ipaddress`, CIDR value can be obtained.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network
ip4 = IPv4Network('0/255.255.255.0')
print(ip4.prefixlen)
print(ip4.with_prefixlen)
```

with results

> 24
> 0.0.0.0/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass both your gateway and mask as a tuple to [`IPv4Network`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network)

```
import ipaddress
gateway = '192.0.2.250'
mask = '255.255.255.0'
network = ipaddress.IPv4Network((gateway, mask), strict=False)
print(network) # 192.0.2.0/24
```

You must pass `strict=False` because the network has host bits set